# Run code after Flask server starts

Tags: python, flask

I want to run some code after I call `app.run`.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
print '1'
app.run(host=config.server_address, port=config.server_port)
print '2'
```

It prints 1, but doesn't print 2 until I stop the server. Why doesn't the second `print` execute immediately?

Comment: To answer your question. It is because that server is actually an infinite loop. Yes, it is the behaviour of Flask. No, you cannot.

Comment: @Sraw - Thanks for your comment, Now i want to call the method using  flask context. how to do this? (after  my server started)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run the flask in a thread.

```
threading.Thread(target=app.run, args=(config.server_address, config.server_port)).start()
```